# Android. How to package a file and then ::fopen it from JNI?

Tags: android

How to package a static file and then be able to ::fopen it from JNI?

I have read about res/raw/blah and R.raw.blah stuff, but when I install app on emulator and do "adb -e shell", cd /data/data/my_app/, ls, the file is not there.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to do the same.
The only thing I could think of was:
copying the file onto the sdcard and read it from there "/sdcard/somefolder/somefile"